# npm ERR! peerinvalid during npm install step of Angular 2 Quickstart

Tags: angular, npm-install

I have node v4.4.0 and npm v2.14.20 installed on OS X (El Capitan).

I'm following steps described on [5 Min Quickstart - ts](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) page that's available on Angular 2 official site.

However I come across the following error when I execute `npm install`.

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package es6-shim@0.35.0 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer angular2@2.0.0-beta.9 wants es6-shim@^0.33.3
```

In order to be able to isolate the problem this is what I have done.

1. Create an empty project folder.
2. On the empty folder I have executed `npm init` with empty values to generate an empty `package.json`.
3. I have added the following dependencies to my package.json.

   ```
   "dependencies": {
     "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.9",
     "es6-shim": "^0.35.0"
   }
   ```
4. I executed `npm install` and observe the same error above.

This is the `peerDependencies` inside `package.json` of `/node_modules/angular2`

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
  "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
  "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
  "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
  "zone.js": "0.5.15"
}
```

Given the `^0.33.3` version requirement for es6-shim peer dependency, shouldn't es6-shim be installed fine with version `0.35.0`? What is the problem that I fail to see?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, except that I have Windows10.
I solved it by upgrading my Node.js from 4.4.1 LTS to 5.9.0 Stable.

Answer (score 3):

Try this version of `package.json`, that should do it

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.9",
    "systemjs": "0.19.24",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "zone.js": "0.5.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.7",
    "typings":"^0.7.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Care to explain how this is different or why it works?

Comment: @aboveyou00 This package.json simply made use of a previous version of es6-shim (0.33.3) . The last error message made this an easy call: `npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer angular2@2.0.0-beta.9 wants es6-shim@^0.33.3`

Answer (score 0):

package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.10",
    "systemjs": "0.19.24",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.7",
    "typings":"^0.7.5",
    "grunt"                : "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-clean"  : "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat" : "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-sass"   : "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-watch"  : "^0.6.1"
  }
}
```

node_modules/angular2/package.json

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.4"
  },
```

Not sure if all that I've done above is exactly correct.
But it's working so far

I think the recent update (https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/package.json) is causing this issue.

Edit: Basically the changes are:

- "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.10"
- "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
- "zone.js": "^0.6.4"